# Use of amsmath binom causes missing number if breqn is used

Tags: errors, compilation-error, breqn

I was hitting the following mysterious error:

```
./xx.tex:7: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   \relax
l.7 \binom{n}{k}
```

and I tracked it down to the breqn and flexisym packages vs. amsmath.  Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\binom{n}{k}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

With either the flexisym or breqn usepackage's left in, I hit the error above, but with neither left in, binom works fine.

I'm running texlive-2019.20200218-1, breqn 0.98h from WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Is this a known problem?  Are there any work arounds?

Comment: Which vintage of TeXlive do you run? The reason I ask is that I cannot reproduce the issue you've encountered on a MacTeX2020 system with all updates installed.

Comment: I am running 2019.20200218-1, breqn 0.98h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue happens when version 0.98i of `breqn` and associated packages is used. I can reproduce it with TeX Live 2019.

Version 0.98j of `mathstyle.sty` was specifically issued to solve the problem, see the [changelog](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/mathstyle.sty?r1=53833&r2=54801) and you can [download it](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/mathstyle.sty?revision=54801&view=co). Save it in the working directory and it should work OK.

Note that the current version of the `breqn` bundle is 0.98k, but I cannot recommend you to upgrade to this version, because other changes might be not compatible with the TeX Live 2019 you seem to be running on.